# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python

im working on a discord number generator i need help with this code error whenever i run it it says this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: I'm sure that this is covered in the Bot API documentation

Comment: What is Bot API documentation?

Comment: you're using `commands.Bot`. Check the documentation on that.

Comment: [`Bot` API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot). It's probably helpful to look at the [`Intents` primer](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when starting back into discord bots. The developers had recently released some larger updates so id recommend un-installing discord and then re-installing it.

`~$ pip uninstall discord`

`~$ pip install discord`

Then make sure your setting intents as these are i assume required now (see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html for more info lol)

Somthing like this should work as it works for me

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as a bot {0.user}".format(client))

client.run('<TOKEN>')
```